# DirectX does not allow double precision math in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, directx, precision, direct3d, sharpdx

I have a large VB.net application that does FEM structural analysis.  It requires double precision math.  The application also uses DirectX for the graphics.  I now know that DirectX intentionally sets the "floating-point unit” (FPU) to single precision by default when it starts.  That is a big problem.  I need to figure out how to start DirectX but preserve the double precision.  Currently I start DirectX with the following:

```
Dev = New Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, Panel2,         
CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, pParams)
```

I have read that using “CreateFlags.FpuPreserve” as shown below will preserve the double precision.  But when I try this DirectX does not start.

```
Dev = New Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, Panel2, CreateFlags.FpuPreserve, pParams)
```

Can anybody tell me how to do start DirectX from with VB.net and preserve the double precision?

Answer (score 1):

First, to get your code to work, you need to still specify software vertex processing. In VB, this is done as `Dev = New Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, Panel2, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing Or CreateFlags.FpuPreserve, pParams)`

Once you've fixed that, you'll find it still doesn't do what you want. `FpuPreserve` corresponds to [D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172527.aspx). This affects the floating-point precision calculations on the *CPU*, not the GPU.

To get double-precision GPU calculations, you first needs to use Direct3D 11 API or higher (it looks like use are using Direct3D 9). Even then double-precision support is an optional feature; you have to query [ID3D11Device::CheckFeatureSupport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476497(v=vs.85).aspx) with [D3D11_FEATURE_DOUBLES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476124(v=vs.85).aspx) to see if it exists.

In SharpDX it would be `device.CheckFeatureSupport(Feature.ShaderDoubles)`, where `device` is of type `Direct3D11.Device`, or `GraphicsDeviceFeatures.HasDoublePrecision` if you are using SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that did it thanks!  The call needed the "Or CreateFlags.FpuPreserve" added to it as shown above, the "or" being critical.  Double precision is then maintained in CPU / FPU calculations, which is exactly what I need.  I don't know what precision is being used in the graphics calculations but I don't care about that.